# "USE statement is not supported to switch between databases" when running query

Tags: php, sql-server, azure-sql-database, freetds, ubuntu-12.10

I get the following error when trying to select a database with `php's` standard `mssql_select_db` function: `USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database. (severity 16)`. So i'm stumped as in where to go from here.

**Connection Code:**

```
$link = mssql_connect('dsn', 'user@server', 'password');

if (!$link) {
   die('Unable to connect!');
}

if (!mssql_select_db('db', $link)) {
   die('Unable to select database!');
}

$result = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM yourtable');

while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
   var_dump($row);
}
```

My system setup is as follows:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- PHP5
- Apache2
- freeTDS
- unixODBC
- SQL Azure

Also I was following this [guide](http://davejamesmiller.com/blog/web-development/connecting-php-to-sql-server-on-debian-ubuntu).

Comment: What are the SQL statements that you are sending to the database?

Comment: Nothing but a simple list all from a table. `SELECT * FROM someTbl`

Comment: Are you calling `mssql_select_db` more than once on the same connection (`$link` variable from tutorial) with different database name?

Comment: Nope. I'm using the exact same script given in the guide I listed above except filled in my credentials to connect properly.

Comment: Run the SQL Profiler tool to intercept queries that come from your client (PHP application) to the server, see if the `USE` statement is being sent more than once...

Comment: Can you post the PHP code that connects to the database and sends query?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server are you using? This is a [known issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974668.aspx) with SQL Azure. If you're not using Azure, please post the connection code, as others have asked.

Comment: @Pondlife it using sql server 10.0 and it is hosted on Azure.

Comment: I have no experience with Azure myself, but the error message is very clear: [you can't change databases with `USE` in SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336288.aspx). I don't know how or if you can prevent your particular client libraries issuing a `USE` command, but I would try removing the `mssql_select_db()` call completely and specify the correct database name in your ODBC DSN. Hopefully that will connect you directly to the database you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to @Pondlife's last comment above and since he has not made it an answer I will do it for him until he posts it himself.

@Pondlife comment:

> I have no experience with Azure myself, but the error message is very
>   clear: you can't change databases with USE in SQL Azure. I don't know
>   how or if you can prevent your particular client libraries issuing a
>   USE command, but I would try removing the mssql_select_db() call
>   completely and specify the correct database name in your ODBC DSN.
>   Hopefully that will connect you directly to the database you want to
>   use. - **PondLife**